# How data is transmitted through a wireless channel (combination of different frequencies)?

Tags: wireless

WiFi has 20 MHz channel. So, channel 1 has frequencies 2400-2420MHz.

Now for simplicity sake, let's just say we have an 8Hz channel. So, we have frequencies 1-8Hz or in other words we have 8 different frequencies in that channel for data transmission.

1Hz has one cycle, 2Hz has two cycles, 3Hz has three cycles and so on. With each frequency has its own cycle, how they are combined together as a channel for data transmission?

Comment: You're forgetting 1.1 Hz, 1.2 Hz, 2.718 Hz, 3.14159 Hz, etc. Also, in the band you're talking about, it's more like an 8 MHz channel as opposed to an 8 Hz channel. Finally, wireless signaling has become very sophisticated, subtle, and complex (and pretty darn cool), with technology supporting some amazing signaling schemes like 512 QAM. There's a huge amount to learn. I would start by doing a web search for "amplitude modulation" and understanding that, then "frequency modulation" and then just go where the internet takes you.

Comment: I think there is an Electrical Engineering forum.  They would provide the best feedback as this is an IEEE technology.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Wifi (aka 802.11x) uses something called Direct Sequence Spread Spectrum (DSSS). More details are here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-sequence_spread_spectrum

In essence, it's not multiple 1Mhz (or, especially 1Hz) frequencies all transmitted as individual channels, but a single transmission channel that is 20MHz wide, meaning its center frequency is 2410MHz (in your example), but that channel is actually spread from 2400Mhz - 2420MHz.

That's a pretty basic explanation, and there are certainly more complicated ways of transmitting a wireless signal, but if you're interested, that link is a pretty good starting point.